# Change Google Chrome’s Process model?

Tags: macos, command-line, google-chrome, tabs, process

Does anyone know how to stop Chrome doing this?

[image]

Chrome seems to group all tabs I open through the same page into one process. If I copy and paste the links individually into separate tabs, it creates new processes, but when I just middle click links, it groups them into one.

I want to force Chrome to create a new process for every tab because when one page locks up, it freezes pretty much all the tabs I have open and if one of the tabs crashes, it takes the rest with it. You can apparently alter Chrome's process model to one called "--process-per-tab" which seems to be what I'm looking for, but when I try and open Chrome with this argument via the terminal, it doesn't work. It's likely I'm not using the correct command; what I tried was:

```
/Applications/"Google Chrome.app"/Contents/MacOS/"Google Chrome" --process-per-tab
```

I'm on OS X and using the latest dev build 5.0.396.0.

Answer (score 3):

`open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --process-per-tab`

Answer (score 1):

### Single process

> To use this mode, open Chrome's
>   properties in the Start menu and add
>   the string '-single-process' (without
>   the quotes) to the end of the Target
>   box. Now, no matter how many tabs you
>   open, the browser will use just one
>   process. <sup>1</sup>

### Single process per site

> If you add the string
>   '-process-per-site' to the Target
>   line, Chrome will open a new process
>   for each tab, but if you open the same
>   site in two tabs, it will run them on
>   the same process. <sup>1</sup>

### Single process per tab

> The string '-process-per-tab' will
>   force Chrome to create a completely
>   new process and use a new memory space
>   for each tab, which is its default*. <sup>1</sup>

<sup>*This doesn't seem to be the default in the recent versions of Chrome.</sup>

---

**References:**

<sup>1</sup> [10 really cool Google Chrome hacks](http://www.techradar.com/news/internet/10-really-cool-google-chrome-hacks-501492?artc_pg=2)

["Easier" instructions](http://www.madrasgeek.com/2010/06/howto-reduce-google-chrome-process-load.html)

Comment: Actually chrome's default for OSX I think is process per site now.